# require a package that has a different file name in lua

Tags: lua, torch

I am very new to Lua, so pardon for the retarded question.

Following [this tutorial](https://github.com/soumith/cvpr2015/blob/master/DQN%20Training%20iTorch.ipynb) I am trying to import DeepMind `dqn` into an iTorch notebook.

I have cloned [this repo](https://github.com/soumith/deepmind-atari) that contains a folder called `dqn` where the source code lives.

I have added the path to the `dqn` folder

```
package.path = package.path .. ";/path/to/dqn/?.lua"
```

When I try to do

```
require 'dqn'
```

I obtain an (expected) error, since there is no file called `dqn.lua` in the folder. The source code of such module is, in fact, contained in the file `NeuralQLearner.lua`.

I have seen the [documentation](http://www.lua.org/pil/15.3.html) that hints at the problem between file and package name.

So my question is: how can I import this module correctly? How can I let Lua know that `dqn` it should actually look for `NeuralQLearner.lua` (without hardcoding into the path I guess)?

Comment: Have you looked at the `train_agent.lua` example script they use in the `run_*` scripts? Have you tried `require("NeuralQLearner")` since you have a `package.path` which contains `/path/to/dqn/?.lua`?

Comment: Thanks, it makes more sense now. I understand now the trick they do via `if not dqn then
    require 'initenv'
end`. I also tried directly `require 'NeuralQLearner'`  and I have a new set of errors, so I think I am making progress :)

Comment: package.path = package.path .. ";/path/to/?.lua;/path/to/?/init.lua;" try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is in:

```
if not dqn then
    require 'initenv'
end
```

put in every file. The `initenv` file will then define what `dqn` is supposed to mean. Once the path to `initenv` is `package.path`, this seems a nice trick to overcome the limitation.